# Can't connect to HBase container on remote SSH server

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hbase

I want to connect to HBase container on remote server that I connect to with ssh through VPN. Let's say it's 10.0.0.10.In /etc/hosts i placed:

```
 10.0.0.10 hbaseaddr
```

In my java code I use hbase-client:

```
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hbaseaddr");
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
```

I get following error:

```
Can not resolve 791995b8a2df, please check your network
```

What is 791995b8a2df? Also, surprisingly, when I have a VPN turned off it just stays idle and does nothing, so it really is connecting to 10.0.0.10, then why do I have this error?
I read that it might be the issue with /etc/hosts. But I have /etc/hosts inside a local machine, /etc/hosts inside machine on 10.0.0.10 and /etc/hosts inside container with HBase.
What can I do to make it work?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `791995b8a2df` seems to be a Docker container ID, which you cannot SSH to nor should edit the hosts file in

Comment: @OneCricketeer you are right this is a container. Do you know by any chance what can I do to connect to it? I have a project that connects to db2 and mysql containers through SSH on the very same server so it is not the matter of the server nor SHH connection by itself. Also it is not the fault of the connections to containers supported by hbase-client as I connected previously to container that I have locally. So this might be maybe the etc/hosts on the machine on the server? I really don't know

Comment: I don't understand the whole VPN thing, but if you exposed this Docker port to the host, then that port is not firewalled from that host to any other machine, the fact it is running in a container is irrelevant. The only problem I see here is that Zookeeper is actually maintaining your client and cross-server connection information, and will store the container hostname rather than the external host, if not configured appropriately (this should still not require a hosts file change)